# different random number in each div

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is probably simple but I can't get it to work.

I have working code that inputs random number inside div but it inputs same random number in all divs on the page.

How can I input **different** random number in each div?
Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    var num = Math.floor((randomNumber * 75) + 15);

    jQuery('#sale').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.savings').append(num);
    });
</script>
```

Yes I'm looping on # since class is inside, should I loop on class itself?
Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 itemcol">          
<div class="">  
<div id="sale" class="sale" style=""><span class="savings"></span>% OFF<br></div>
```

SOLVED. Here is the final code if someone else finds it useful, changed $ to jQuery and adjusted numbers to go between 15-75.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#sale .savings").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).text(createRandom());
    });

function createRandom() {
        var Num = Math.floor((Math.random() * (75 - 15) + 1) + 15 );
        return Num;
    } 
});     
</script>
```

Comment: you generated your number OUTSIDE of the loop, and it never changes INSIDE the loop...

Comment: you are looping with id ? #sale is you id on which you are looping and appending in .savings class ?

Comment: Please check the answer and comment ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#sale .savings").each(function(){
        $(this).text(createRandom());
    })

    function createRandom() {
        var Num = Math.floor((Math.random() * (75 - 15) + 1) + 15 );
        return Num;
    }       
})
```

**Final code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#sale .savings").each(function(){
    $(this).text(createRandom());
   })
  
  function createRandom() {
    var Num = Math.floor((Math.random() * (75 - 15) + 1) + 15 );
    return Num;
    }       
})
```

```css
.savings {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sale">
  <div class="savings"></div>
  <div class="savings"></div>
  <div class="savings"></div>
  <div class="savings"></div>
</div>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That worked, I had to change $ to jQuery but it worked.

Comment: Its a big process isin't ;)

Comment: Yes, Thank you!  Now just a minor thing random numbers are going pass the 75. I thought my code was filtering between 15-75?

Comment: @DamirGasparlin ,  if you want number between 15-75 , contains 15 and 75 , 'Math.floor((Math.random() * (75 - 15) + 1) + 15 )' .

Answer (score 0):

from you code, i assume, you want to loop on all the div's having **saving** class and append different random number with each of them.Try the below code.

```
jQuery('.savings').each(function() {
 var randomNumber = Math.random();
   var num = Math.floor((randomNumber * 75) + 15);
      $(this).append(num);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: That returned same result

Comment: @DamirGasparlin those div's having saving class ?

Comment: why you are looping on id ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are storing a value in a variable, and print out the variable all the time without updating it in the loop.

```
<script>
   var randomNumber = Math.random();
   jQuery('#sale').each(function() {
     var num = Math.floor((randomNumber * 75) + 15);
     if(jQuery(this).hasClass('.savings')){
       jQuery(this).append(num);
     }
   });
</script>
```

You could also do something like the following:

```
<script>
   var randomNumber = Math.random();
   jQuery('.savings').each(function() {
     var num = Math.floor((randomNumber * 75) + 15);
     jQuery(this).text(num);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Returned same result, all .savings divs have same random number

Comment: Well, perhaps you should be looping `jQuery('.savings').each(fu...` updated the answer btw.